# Gulp webp function not respecting watch command

Tags: asynchronous, gulp, gulp-watch, webp

Ok, so I am using the typical image minification process. I have functions for jpg, pngs and I have a separate function to convert those to webp.

I have the following gulpfile (only the relevant parts are here):

```
    function clean(done) {
      rimraf(folder.public_img, done);
    }

    function images() {
      return gulp.src([folder.preimages+'/**/*.{gif,png,jpg,svg}'])
        .pipe(cache(imagemin([
          imageminPngquant({
              speed: 1,
              quality: [0.95, 1]
          }),
          imageminZopfli({
              more: true
          }),
          imageminMozjpeg({
              quality: 65
          }),
        ])))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(folder.public_img));
    }

    gulp.task('webp', () =>
        gulp.src([folder.preimages+'/**/*.{gif,png,jpg}'])
            .pipe(webp({
                quality: 65,
                method: 6
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(folder.public_img))
    );

    function serve() {
        gulp.watch(folder.preimages+"/**/*.{gif,png,jpg,svg}", images);
        gulp.watch(folder.preimages+"/**/*.{gif,png,jpg}", webp);
    }

    gulp.task('clean', clean);
    gulp.task('images', images);
    gulp.task('serve', gulp.series('clean', 'images', 'webp', serve));
    gulp.task('default', gulp.series('clean', 'images', 'webp', serve));
```

So, basically when I run `gulp` the first time, all the processes run fine and the webp images are generated. BUT, if I add a new image, the `images()` function runs, but for some reason the `webp()` function doesn't execute, it's as if it doesn't see changes, and I have it configured the same way as images.

I tried two alternatives:

1. I added the webp process directly inside the `images()` function, but that way my JPG and PNG files were directly converted to webp and I didn't have fallback images.
2. I tried to create the webp function with the same format as the others `function webp() { ... }`, but when I tried to run gulp it showed this error:

   The following tasks did not complete: default, 
   Did you forget to signal async completion?

So I found that I could use the format above `gulp.task('webp', () =>...` and that works, but doesn't respect the watch function. I think it could be related to the function to name assignation in the end of the file, but I am not that familiar with the syntax.

What should I change so that it watches correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to recreate your code and get it to work as follows:

In creating your gulp tasks, something goofy seems to be happening because you've created a series of tasks to run with your `gulp.task('serve')`. Instead, you can write out your tasks like this:

```
gulp.task(clean);
gulp.task(images);
gulp.task(serve);
gulp.task('default', gulp.series(clean, images, webp, serve));
```

You may want to call your `webp` function something else - I was getting a conflict because of also importing `gulp-webp` as `const = webp`. You also don't need to put quotation marks around the name of the function in the task and then also reference it in the task again. So `gulp.task(clean)` works just fine. You don't need `gulp.task('clean', clean)`.

You can probably also write your default task as follows:

```
gulp.task('default', gulp.series(clean, serve);
```

This had the same effect for me as also including the images and webp tasks in the series. This setup worked for me. Running `gulp`, it first ran the clean function to remove the `public_img` folder, then ran `images` followed by `webp`. It worked up the initial run as well as when I added a new image to the `preimages` folder.

**Update**

Here's the complete gulpfile I got to work:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
const rimraf = require('rimraf');
const webp = require('gulp-webp');

const folder = {
  preimages: 'src/images',
  public_img: 'src/public_img',
};

function clean(done) {
  rimraf(folder.public_img, done);
}

function images() {
  return gulp
    .src([folder.preimages + '/**/*.{gif,png,jpg,svg}'])
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(folder.public_img));
}

function webpTask() {
  return gulp
    .src([folder.preimages + '/**/*.{gif,png,jpg}'])
    .pipe(webp())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(folder.public_img));
}

function serve() {
  gulp.watch(folder.preimages + '/**/*.{gif,png,jpg,svg}', images);
  gulp.watch(folder.preimages + '/**/*.{gif,png,jpg}', webpTask);
}

gulp.task('clean', clean);
gulp.task('images', images);
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('clean', 'images', webpTask, serve));
```

Notes: I removed the `gulp serve` task. I couldn't get that to work under any configuration. I think you are running into a conflict by naming both the task and the function `serve`, although I'm not 100% positive. I changed the `webp` task name to `webpTask`, as I was getting a conflict by naming both the webp import and the webp function `webp`. I didn't include any of the webp() or imagemin() configuration options, but that shouldn't matter.

You should also be able to remove the calls for both the `images` and `webpTask` functions in the `gulp default` task, as running the `serve` function should trigger both of those.

This setup worked for me both when adding new images to my `preimages` folder while the `gulp default` task was running as well as when restarting the `gulp default` task.

FYI: I'm using gulp version 4.0.1., but I don't think that should make a difference for this.

Comment: I am not sure how your example is working, could you update it with the full gulpfile? Just to add some info, the original gulpfile was generated by foundation-cli and that's the way the guys from foundation prepared the serve and default functions. When I tried to modify my gulpfile with your seggestions, once it got stuck waiting at serve, but didn't do any of the processes in serve, I think it was just watching for changes but didn't generate anything, so I do need to execute it when I run `gulp` and then I need it to watch. Everything else works, I just need to fix the webp watch.

Comment: I added my full gulpfile above. Hope it helps. Everything worked fine for me using this setup.

Comment: I adjusted your code to mine and it worked, I think the problem was a mixture between the webp variable and the serve function. Now it's working!

Comment: By the way, I also currently have another question related to gulp, you could check it in case you have any info related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56677452/pngs-generated-with-gulp-using-imageminpngquant-imageminzopfli-dont-work-on-m